# What is the role of Tick () function is in gem5?

Tags: gem5

In many classes, such as CPU, fetch, and decode etc., I see that there is a Tick() function, which is called at the beginning of the simulation. What is the purpose of this function?

Comment: Taking a look at the (fairly small) documentation of these functions (grep -nr -B 4 "void tick()" src/cpu) and their respective implementations might help you understand. You should also make sure to ask this question on the user mailing list (https://www.gem5.org/mailing_lists/) to increase your chances of being answered.